Residency and car registration
My domicile is in Virginia but I'm in Texas taking care of my dad who is 94.  I don't plan on permanently moving here, but do I need to change my license and vehicle registration to Texas while I'm here?
Cindy

Is there a specific address in Virginia that you intend to return to?

How long do you intend to stat in Texas?

In Texas you must register your car within 30 days of becoming a resident, and you must get a Texas driver's license within 90 days.
However, I don't think you become a resident if you're only there temporarily to take care of your father. Most of the information I can find about establishing residency comes from state college website, since residents get special consideration; it's not clear that the same criteria applies to the DMV regulations.
One part of this criteria is that you must have lived in Texas for 12 consecutive months. So I think you would have to take care of your father for 13 months before you have to re-register your car.
